# Kotlin, IntelliJ: math operator not working

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

- Ubuntu Mate 20.04
- IntelliJ IDEA Community 2020.2 EAP, installed through Snap
- Kotlin 1.3.72, installed through Snap
- JRE 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~16.04-b08
- Project set up as Kotlin: JVM|IDEA using SDK 11 (java 11.0.6)

Code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var experiencePoints: Int = 5
    experiencePoints += 5
    println(experiencePoints)
}
```

has a red squiggly line under the "+=" and produces the following error:

> Error:(3, 22) Kotlin: Cannot access 'java.io.Serializable' which is a supertype of 'kotlin.Int'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Changed the code to the following:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var experiencePoints: Int = 5
    experiencePoints = experiencePoints + 5
    println(experiencePoints)
}
```

Red squiggly line beneath the "+" character and same error.

This is Day 1 for me, following example in "Kotlin Programming, The Big Nerd Ranch Guide" by Skeen and Greenhalgh. No idea what to do about this error.

Comment: Where did you ran your program from Intellij or Gradle? If from Intellij did you selected the JDK on Project Structure, (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S)?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu: I ran from IntelliJ. Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S doesn't do anything. Do you know where I would find that in the menus?

Comment: File -> ProjectStructure?

Comment: Down the left-hand side there's:
Project Settings: Project, Modules, Libraries, Facets, Artifacts.
Platform Settings: SDKs, Global Libraries

Comment: Project -> Project SDK

Comment: This is set as SDK 11 (java 11.0.6)

Comment: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/cannot-access-java-io-serializable-which-is-a-supertype-of/16595/5 a similar issue addressed here. Suggests to try changing java version or try to do a reimport gradle (double shift -> search gradle -> on window select reimport gradle).

Answer (score 1):

I had this in Intellij 2021.2 Ultimate on MacOS Catalina, and I did have the JDK installed. But in File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project -> Project SDK I had the Kotlin SDK selected. Makes sense, it's a Kotlin project, right? Wrong, it needs to be the Java JDK selected here.

Also under Platform Settings -> SDKs -> Kotlin SDK I was missing the Classpath. I'm not sure if this was necessary, but it was that way when I created a new Kotlin project from scratch. I ran into trouble importing an existing combined Java/Kotlin project.

Comment: There is no "**Project SDK**" anymore, just "**Android SDK**":
https://imgur.com/a/6cJDomt

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I didn't have default-jdk installed. Once I did, I found that there were extra options under File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK. I added user/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 java version "11.0.7" and the problem resolved.